# XPath to return string concatenation splitted by html tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath, string-concatenation

How can I return string value containing the concatenated values using an XPath expression?

```
<div>
This text node (1) should be returned.
<em>And the value of this element.</em>
And this.
</div>

<div>
This text node (2) should be returned.
And this.
</div>

<div>
This text node (3) should be returned.
<em>And the value of this element.</em>
And this.
</div>
```

The returned value should be an array of strings split by `div` element:

```
"This text node (1) should be returned. And the value of this element. And this."
"This text node (2) should be returned. And this."
"This text node (3) should be returned. And the value of this element. And this."
```

Is this possible in a single XPath expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

Cannot do with pure XPath 1.0.  Instead, select the `div` elements:

```
//div
```

and then apply space normalization of the string values of each `div` element in the language hosting the XPath library call.

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
//div/normalize-space()
```

will return the normalized string value of all `div` elements in the document:

```
This text node (1) should be returned. And the value of this element. And this.
This text node (2) should be returned. And this.
This text node (3) should be returned. And the value of this element. And this.
```

as requested.

Comment: Just to amplify this, the reason it can't be done in XPath 1.0 is that your desired result (a sequence of strings) doesn't exist in the XPath 1.0 data model. You can return a sequence of nodes -- but only nodes that already exist in the input; XPath 1.0 has no way to modify the content of a node or to create a new node.